Why does Regex.IsMatch return true for a newline as input when expecting zero to 4 digits?
I'm trying to validate some user input for the country code of a phone number. The country code is optional, but when it contains a value it should be 1 to 4 digits. I wrote a regular expression and expected the regular expression to fail when passing "\n" in C#. It appeared to match, so I popped open the C# interactive console in Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.8.6). Indeed, the pattern was matching a newline character unexpectedly. My experiments below:
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Interactive Compiler version 4.8.0-7.23572.1 ()
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
Type "#help" for more information.
> using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
> Regex.IsMatch("\n", "^[0-9]{0,4}$")
true
> Regex.IsMatch("\n", "^[0-9]{0,4}$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
true
> Regex.IsMatch("\n", "^[0-9]{0,4}$", RegexOptions.Singleline)
true
> Regex.IsMatch("\n", "^[0-9]{0,4}$", RegexOptions.None)
true
> Regex.IsMatch("\n", "^[0-9]{0,4}$", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
true
> Regex.IsMatch("\n", "^\\d{0,4}$")
true

Screenshot of the C# interactive console:

Just out of curiosity, I opened the Google Chrome console and entered this JavaScript:
let pattern = /^\d{0,4}$/
undefined
pattern.test("\n")
false
pattern = /^[0-9]{0,4}$/
pattern.test("\n")
false

Screenshot of Chrome:

This has definitely left me scratching my head.
Why does Regex.IsMatch report that a newline matches (beginning of line); zero or more digits; (end of line) when given a string with a single newline - "\n"?

I think that as described here "The $ anchor specifies that the preceding pattern must occur at the end of the input string, or before \n at the end of the input string." there is a match as the pattern ^[0-9]{0,4}$ also accepts an empty string.

For JavaScript here is a note about using the anchors with and without the m flag. For me pattern = /^[0-9]{0,4}$/; will return false, and pattern = /^[0-9]{0,4}$/m; will return true.

Just note that in C# regex, $ without the multiline flag can match a position before the final newline char, so you should always use \z anchor to match the very end of the string. In JS ECMAScript regex, $ without any m flag behaves as \z in .NET regex. If multiline is on, in JS regex it matches before \r and \n (and \u2028 and \u2029), in .NET, it will only match before the newline, \n, char (as . in JS regex matches any char but CR, LF, Paragraph and Line separators - \u2028 and \u2029 - and in .NET regex . matches any char but LF). That is all there is to it.

The pattern that you use ^[0-9]{0,4}$ matches 0-4 times a digit, and will also match an empty string.
For C# there is a description about "End of String or Line: $"

The $ anchor specifies that the preceding pattern must occur at the
end of the input string, or before \n at the end of the input string.

For JavaScript there is a description about using the anchors ^ and $

If the m flag is set, ... and $ also matches if the character to the
right is a line terminator.

For C# it can match the empty string before the newline, and for JavaScript it can if the m flag is set.


const pattern1 = /^[0-9]{0,4}$/;
console.log(pattern1.test("\n"));

const pattern2 = /^[0-9]{0,4}$/m;
console.log(pattern2.test("\n"));



